# Trigger (change) of a slider after a few seconds in Angular

Tags: angular

Using [ngx-ui](https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-ui/#slider) slider for a year range. This is the HTML part:

```
<ngx-slider 
    [(ngModel)]="globalYearSelection" 
    [step]="1" 
    [filled]="false" 
    [min]="1990" 
    [max]="2015" 
    (change)="onChangeYear($event.value)">
</ngx-slider>
```

And this is my component with the `onChangeYear()` function:

```
onChangeYear(value) {
  this.globalYearSelection = value;
  this.getAllChartsData();
}
```

As you can see, when I change the value of the slider, I update the `this.globalYearSelection` and then I call a function that has several HTTP requests to get some data.

However, while I change the value of the slider, the `this.getAllChartsData()` is called multiple times for each step of the slider.

I tried to do it like this:

```
  onChangeYear(value) {
    this.globalYearSelection = value;
    setTimeout(() => this.getAllChartsData(), 2000);
  }
```

To be sure that it will trigger the HTTP requests only after 2 seconds, but the result was to wait 2 seconds and then fire all the requests for all the values I slided at once.

I tried also to use `(blur)="onChangeYear($event.value)"` but it is not compatible with the component.

Any idea what I can do?

Comment: You want to trigger your server call after getting the updated year value correct?

Comment: Yes. But the updated year value is updated as I slide on the slider and changing values.

Comment: you want value after slide event or while you are sliding ?

Comment: I want to finish the sliding. Then when you mouse over and you finish, then trigger the HTTP requests

Comment: And this is tied to a ReactiveForm, I believe? If yes, what you can do is listen for valueChanges on this field on the form and call debounce on it, so it will delay the calls. This is more or less the same approach as preventing from firing multiple calls when searching on a text field.

Comment: @jpgrassi no.. it is not tied on a Form.. It is just a component on the page.

Comment: Can you hook it up on a formGroup? If you can.. then problem is solved :). I looked into the source code for the slider.. and there's no event for when the slide is finished. But even if they had wouldn't help you. What you need is a debounce on the stream of values.

Comment: Tried installing this package on a brand new angular cli and it doesn't work. On the repo it says it's in development so.. I personally would look for something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it , there is no need of `(change)="onChangeYear($event.value)"`

Component side :

```
sliderValue = 0;

sliderEvent() {
    alert(this.sliderValue);
    // call your api for fetching data
    // this.sliderValue will be updated as it's
    // already 2 way binded
}
```

Template side :

```
<ngx-slider
  [(ngModel)]="sliderValue"
  [step]="5"
  [filled]="true"
  [min]="10"
  [max]="200"
  (mouseup)="sliderEvent()">
</ngx-slider>
```

---

Here is the link to the working demo :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-slider

Comment: That's great! Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You can use this event

**userChangeEnd**

will do the same behavior you wanted.

the right marked solution is having an issue:

in **(mouseup)** event if you pulled the slider and moved the mouse away from the slider, the slider value will be changed but the event will not be triggered

Answer (score 2):

'ngx-slider' will only provide us triger point 'userChange'

<ngx-slider [(value)]="56" [options]="options" (userChange)="funcTion()">

https://github.com/angular-slider/ngx-slider/blob/master/typedoc-theme/README.md